# Converting ASP.NET MVC IEnumerable view model to json array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a calendar in ASP.NET MVC that would be dynamically populated based on event data retrieved from a database. Currently, I have a calendar that works as I intend but the problem is that the input for the calendar is json array of objects. In my view, I am passing a viewmodel that has a single property which is an `IEnumerable` list of a datamodel class. In the view I am trying to then access this list and convert it into a loop such that it works with the already built calendar that is reading json array of objects

//Accepted/working input of the Calendar

```
events: [
                {
                    title: "Birthday Party",
                    start: new Date(2020, 0, 1), 
                    end: new Date(2020, 0, 13),
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party 2',
                    start: new Date(2019, 11, 9),
                    end: new Date(2019, 11, 13),
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(2019, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(2019, m, 29),
                }
            ],
```

//calendarview model

```
 public class CalendarViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CalendarDataModel> data { get; set; }
}
```

`CalendarDataModel`:

```
public class CalendarDataModel
{
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public int StartYear { set; get; }
    public int StartMonth { set; get; }
    public int StartDay { set; get; }

    public int EndYear { set; get; }
    public int EndMonth { set; get; }
    public int EndDay { set; get; }

}
```

I simply want the final result to be that the information being transferred into the view via the viewmodel gets converted to a json format that the calendar built in javascript can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
var model = @Html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(Model.data));
        var events = [];
        model.forEach(function (val) {
            var event = {
                title: val.Description,
                start: new Date(val.StartYear, val.StartMonth, val.StartDay),
                end: new Date(val.EndYear, val.EndMonth, val.EndDay)
            }

            alert(val.StartYear + "-" + val.StartMonth + "-" + val.StartDay)
            alert(val.EndYear + "-" + val.EndMonth + "-" + val.EndDay)
            events.push(event);
        });
```

"events" variable will contain the data your calendar is looking for.

Comment: just some naming correction. This solution worked thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

So convert it to JSON.

In your view:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

<script type="javascript">
    var events = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.data))
</script>
```

You may need to fix up the property names using `[JsonProperty("prop name here")]` attributes on your model.

Comment: should this still allow the new date object to work as expected? After trying to assign the final events variable to the event object no error is shown but the results isnt as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Json class from the `System.Web.Helpers` namespace.

In your javascript:

```
var events = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.data));
```

This will give you an array that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        'Description': ...,
        'StartYear': ...,
        'StartMonth': ...,
        'StartDay': ...,
        'EndYear': ...,
        'EndMonth': ...,
        'EndDay': ...
    },
    ... 
]
```

In my experience, using `Json.Encode` without `Html.Raw` is dangerous because it can result in invalid encoding of characters, so be sure to wrap your encoded Json with that method.

You can then loop through your model just like any other array of Json objects:

```
for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    // do something with events[i]
}
```

Comment: should this still allow the new date object to work as expected?